# How to increase image to full screen?

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer, revolution-slider

I have just set up a WordPress website and would like to have the slider image set to full screen. I currently have [Slider Revolution](https://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380) and [WPBakery Page Builder](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431) plugins set up.

Everything is set up just that the image is doesn't overlap the menu at the top.

I'd like the image to show full screen like this one on this website https://www.rentmycaravan.com/

My website is [www.hiremytent.com](http://www.hiremytent.com).

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with css as shown below. Just be sure to replace "image.jpg" with your background image.

```css
body{height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background-image:url(image.jpg);/*your background image*/  
   background-repeat:no-repeat;/*we want to have one single image not a repeated one*/  
   background-size:cover;/*this sets the image to fullscreen covering the whole screen*/  
   /*css hack for ie*/     
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.image.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

You could also do it by using some jQuery plugins:

- http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/
- http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```css
body{height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background-image:url(test-image-camping.jpg);/*your background image*/  
   background-repeat:no-repeat;/*we want to have one single image not a repeated one*/  
   background-size:cover;/*this sets the image to fullscreen covering the whole screen*/  
   /*css hack for ie*/     
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.test-image-camping.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='test-image-camping.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Alternatively, you could also set the image to the bottom layer:

```
<img src='test-image-camping.jpg' style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1;'>
```